# Reusable method for searching

Tags: java, search

I have a Product class with fields named (String)code, (String)name, (Double)price and (Date)expiration with each own getter and setter method. I have another class ListProduct that contains a field List named productList. Below is a ListProduct class i created a method to return all the product searched by product name only.

```
public List<Product> SearchItemByName(ListProduct list,
        String name) {

    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product prod : list.productList) {

        if (prod.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
            products.add(prod);
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

What I need to know is how to make the above a reusable method that can search the list not only by its name,like using lambda expression or anonymous method.

Comment: What is `lProduct` in `new ArrayList<lProduct>()`, and do you have the option to use Java 8?

Comment: Lambdas are only supported in Java 8. And Java 8 already defines the [Predicate](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/Predicate.html) interface and [methods](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) using it to do what you want. If you're not using Java 8, then consider using Guava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the condition into an interface:

```
public interface ProductAccepter {
   public boolean accept(Product product);
}

public List<Product> searchItem(ListProduct list, ProductAccepter accepter) {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product prod : list.productList) {
        if (accepter.accept(prod))
            products.add(prod);
        }
    }
    return products;
}
```

Then to call it, you can use an anonymous class:

```
final String name = "foo";
List<Product> products = searchItem(list, new ProductAccepter() {
    public boolean accept(Product product) {
        return product.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I access the ProductAccepter on other class?

Comment: Declare `ProductAccepter` in a separate file called `ProductAccepter.java`. ie it should be a normal top level class/interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Guava and pass to this method Predicate:

```
new Predicate<Product>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Product input) {
        // here check for desired conditions
    }
};
```

Then you can use Iterables to filter your collection:

```
return Iterables.filter(productList, predicate);
```

So your method will looks like:

```
public List<Product> SearchItemByName(ListProduct list, Predicate<Product> predicate) {
        return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(list.productList, predicate));
}

searchItemByName(list, new Predicate<Product>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Product input) {
        // here check for desired conditions
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you do me a favor for me to understand it better? Please write in a condition where it compares the product's expiration to a certain data.

Comment: then you have to replace name with a date and change the apply method to compare dates. Also, so not use Double for price, use BigDecimal, or you'll have round issues

Comment: too bad java don't have something such as a static method to retrieve a known class attribute. Something that JPA generated metamodel Criteria artificially has to generate :-(